# import files from same/parent directory into python files for uploading as pypi package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-import, pypi

I know there are a lot of questions concerning import of files in other directories, but I didn't found a solution for my problem:

I have written a small project with this structure:

```
project
 |-setup.py
 |-... some files (README, LICENSE, etc)
 |-package_name
   |-__main__.py
   |-__init__.py
   |-run.py
   |-script
     |-__init__.py
     |-calculations.py
   |-GUI
     |-__init__.py
     |-window.py
```

in **main**.py for example i want to import run.py. I tried

```py
import run
```

which worked fine when executed locally. But after uploading and installing the project to PyPi.org, I tried to run it by `python3 -m package_name` and got an import error:

```
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/package_name/__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'run'
```

so I tried imports like `from . import run` or `from ..script import calculations` (from ./GUI/window.py) or

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from script import calculations
```

But none of these worked from the PyPi-package.

My setup.py looks like:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={'deputat': ['GUI/pictures/*.svg']},
    ...
)
```

I hope someone can help me fix this after hours of useless tries and about 100 new verions uploaded to pypi (mybe not 100, but a lot of :p)

Thanks for any help and advise!

Comment: `from . import run` or better `from package_name import run` should be good enough. If not, seems to me like there's something wrong going on.

Comment: ```from package_name import run``` seems to work, but I think its loading the run from the installed package instead of the run inside the package directory (which is the same for running the project as pypi package, but if i do not install the pypi package and download the project from github for example, I will get an import error, since package_name will not be found?!)

Comment: If there is a `package_name` both in your current working directory (for example cloned with _git_) and in _site packages_ (for example installed with _pip_), then there is a risk of conflict, yes. So you have to make sure there is only one `package_name` that is importable at any given time.